# Map with polyhedral graphs as keys

Tags: data-structures, graph, dictionary, graph-theory

I want a data structure where the keys are polyhedra (undirected 3-connected planar graphs; in my case they will probably mostly be <30 vertices), looked up such that equality is isomorphism. Is there an efficient way to implement this mapping?

I've researched and reflected a bit but have not come up with a solution. It seems like the solution is likely to be one of

- A custom data structure that uses the graph itself to look up the data
- A binary search tree (or other similar tree), which would require a well-defined ordering. (I have my doubts that such an ordering exists)
- A hash table, which would require a good hash. I cannot immediately come up with one any better than "number of vertices" or similar.

How can I get efficient lookup?

Comment: Could you provide some more details on what kind of graphs you have? bidirectional? size?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every polyhedral graph is planar. The isomorphism problem for planar graphs is polynomial time. It doesn't have the unknown-but-thought-to-be-large complexity of the general graph isomorphism problem. Although efficient, the algorithms are not simple and rely on some fairly deep mathematics for their analysis.

The original paper (insofar as I know) is Hopcroft's 1971 paper *An N log N Algorithm for Isomorphism of Planar Triply Connected Graphs*, available from Stanford as a [scanned copy](ftp://reports.stanford.edu/pub/cstr/reports/cs/tr/71/192/CS-TR-71-192.pdf). There's a fair amount of work on this problem. A more recent paper is [*Algorithm and Experiments in Testing Planar Graphs for Isomorphism*](http://www.emis.de/journals/JGAA/accepted/2004/KuklukHolderCook2004.8.3.pdf) which has the virtue of a number of references to existing algorithms and running time comparisons between them. This paper presents an algorithm that assigns a unique code to each graph, which incidentally also generates a well-defined ordering. Their best results in that paper for small graphs was the algorithm of Brendan McKay in [*Practical Graph Isomorphism*](http://cs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/papers/pgi.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! At first glance, it sounds like Kikluk et al.'s _JGAA_ paper provides exactly what I need. I'll be looking more closely into it.

Answer (score 2):

As graph isomorphism is not that easily checked, I would recommend minimizing the number of isomorphism-checks. Your hash table seems a good start. You need a good key to maximize resolution

Suppose you use the array `[V,out_1,in_1,out_2,in_2,...]` 
with `V`=nr vertices, `out_i`=ith highest outdegree , `in_1`=indegree of the node with the ith highest outdegree (first sort on the outdegree and then on the indegree). This would be slightly more efficient (but you might have thought of something like that already) then your nr vertices.

The above is a rather crude example, you could actually use any (combination of) [graph invariant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_property#Graph_invariants_and_graph_isomorphism) as a key for your table. Depending on the number of graphs you have and their similarity, you should select the one that gives you the most difference/resolution power (using the nr vertices is useless if all your graphs have the same number of vertices).

Using the invariants, you could construct a tree as well as they could be used to create the ordering that you need. The array example above could be used as it defines a complete order but you could again use any invariant

Comment: Thanks for the attention and reply!